# How to show both drawer button and back button in Flutter app?

Tags: navigation-drawer, back, flutter, appbar

For faster navigation to root pages in deep navigation, both Back and Drawer icon buttons need to be shown in [AppBar](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html).

[image]

How to do that in a Flutter app?

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your toolbar widget with Row

```
....
Row toolbar = new Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    new Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
    new Icon(Icons.menu),
    new Expanded(child: new Text(widget.title)),
    new Icon(Icons.arrow_forward)
  ]
);

return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: toolbar,
  ),
....
```

Here it is the result
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but how to restore default AppBar? Back button and menu button are, in fact, automatic in default AppBar setup. Now it seems, all custom make and needed to add functionality and possibly lost features like pin, float, behaviour of title.

Comment: There's the problem with mixing different forms of navigation. All three (Stack, Tab, and Drawer) are compatible, but not naturally.